# Add Fabric app (Twitter) without Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter-fabric, fastlane

**I have this situation:** I need to build my app on the command line, but I need to make changes too. (The tool I would be using is Fastlane).

I could enter the api keys externally, but the question is: How do I create a Fabric app without opening Xcode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a Fabric account, all you need is the organisation API key. On the first launch of a new app, the app will automatically be created on Fabric.

Comment: Hey Felix! The problem is that **the same project will be used for several apps**, and I won't be running every app I made, because it's a semi-automatized system.By now the workaround is using Twitter app manager, which is not Fabric. I'm still working on it, when it's finished I'll try to publish some kind of documentation. Thanks!

Comment: So you're using a different bundle identifier, but the same Xcode project?

Comment: That's right! I make a Info.plist dynamically with the right bundle id, Facebook app id, and everything needed for the app.

Comment: I just tried, changing the bundle identifier and running the project works. The app will automatically get created on Crashlytics.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll revisit the problem when I have time, maybe I didn't do it the right way or something... Thanks Felix! Great to have people like you online! :)